# Yii can not find the translation

Tags: php, yii, module, translation

I'm trying to use Yii:t() inside a module, but for some reason it isn't working, and I see on the website the translation id, "article_was_not_found", instead of its text, "The article was not found."

The code inside the module's controller:

```
throw new CHttpException(404, Yii::t('NewsModule.article', 'article_was_not_found'));
```

The content of protected/modules/news/messages/he/article.php:

```
return array(
    'article_was_not_found' => 'The article was not found.'
);
```

('he' is set as the source language inside the config)

I tried a few different option: 'NewsModule.article', 'newsModule.article', 'article', 'news.article' - however, no one seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't set language. You must set your language to `he` like below:

```
Yii::app()->language="he";
```

The other way is to set a default language in config file:

```
'language' => 'he',
```

Please note that the correct way is:

```
Yii::t('NewsModule.article', 'article_was_not_found');
```

Which `NewsModule` is your module class name.